# Qt open file with cyrillic path

Tags: c++, qt, file, path

I need to open file with C++/Qt. I opened it, but if there is cyrillic symbols in the file path i get:

/home/shk/?????????/test.txt

How can i fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: So opening the file works? The problem is the display of the path then? Where? debug output, or a widget?

Answer (score 2):

```
QTextCodec::setCodecForTr(QTextCodec::codecForName("utf8"))
tr(line.toAscii()) ( toUtf8 and toLatin1);
```

and

```
 QTextCodec::setCodecForTr(QTextCodec::codecForName("utf8"))
 tr(line.toAscii()) ( toUtf8 and toLatin1);
```

[this](http://pepper.troll.no/s60prereleases/doc/linguist-hellotr.html) maybe helpful